# Submit iOS app to Store without access to Developer Program account, but a provisioning profile and Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have the distribution certificate and provisioning profile for the application. But the client doesn't share the Store Credentials with me and i'm finding it difficult to upload the app to store without the store credentials(with membership). But i see in web that its possible to submit app without the store credentials of the client. Kindly help.

Comment: You say "i see in web that its possible [...]".  Where do you see that?

Comment: client can safety create iTunes Connect account for you with developer role. you can't upload app without it

Comment: @sage444: does that mean i do not need to join the developer program?

Comment: @shahalpk technically yes, to upload app to store you need only account in itunes connect. I know this because I have one account for developer program and another for itunes connect

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The automatic uploading from xcode is just saving the credentials for the iTunes Connect account(s).